# How to convert one map to another map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have ane map that maps ids to integers. I need to create another map which will map ids to a particular type (interval) which has a tuple of integers.

```scala
val secondValue = 5
input: Map[Identifier, Integer]
val newInput: Map[Identifier, Interval] = input.map({
       case (x, d) => (x -> Interval(d, secondValue))
})
```

Interval is defined in a file and it is imported here. This code does not work as newInput is not changed. Can you guide me where I am doing wrong?

The required type of input is Identifier -> Integer and newInput is Identifier -> [Integer, Integer], but I am getting Identifier -> Integer for both input and newInput.

Comment: why do you think that your code doesn't work? could you specify expected and actual results?

Comment: I want input and newInput as bellow. input: id -> 3, newInput: id -> (3, 5). But I am getting id -> 3 for both input and newInput.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the expected output. You have more options for formatting that way.

Comment: Post your Interval source. Does it, by a chance, have an `apply` method? That would explain the difference in types you're getting. Also, you don't need parentheses around `x -> Interval(d, secondValue)`, nor do you need the ones around map invocation

Comment: I am not getting the difference in the type which I want. I am getting the exact same map for input and newInput, which I do not want. I do have an apply method in Interval, but just adds another integer number with the first value.

Comment: do you use REPL, worksheet, smth any? your code looks nice in common

Comment: Thank you. No, I did not use these. Thanks for the suggestion. I can try them.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine. It can be simplified some: `input.mapValues(Interval(_,secondValue))`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not providing Identifier and Interval, I created my own. After initializing input properly, your code seems to work fine:

```
case class Interval(x: Int, d: Int)
case class Identifier(x:Int)

val secondValue = 5
val input: Map[Identifier, Integer] = Map(Identifier(1) -> 10)

val newInput: Map[Identifier, Interval] = input.map({
  case (x, d) => 
    x -> Interval(d, secondValue)
})
```

Comment: Even my code was fine. I was trying to print some value which was being changed inside the Interval. I did not see that before. Sorry.